# Local git repository on a windows client where remote server is on a remote apache server

Tags: git, iis-8.5, github

Please forgive me if I am asking a repetitive question but I am new to using git repositories and I don't know where to start. Here is my how I want to set up my repository:

1. Create a local repository that the dev site will run under IIS and MySQL database both on my Windows machine. I will eventually export data to a remote server once I'm done developing the site. The HSP doesnt allow for remote access to the database so I will host the database from my static IP which is a windows machine.
2. The remote server will be running a wordpress site on an apache server so the wp-config will be different which I will figure out.
3. I will likely share the repository on Github if the project gets too large for me to work on my own.

I know this is alot to ask for so maybe someone could point me in the right direction as to where I need to start my research.

A) Should I focus on Git from the command line 
B) Create a shared repository on Github?

Once again, I apologize in advance, but I am a little confused regarding GIt and Github and how I can use them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the development environment you like and can be productive in. Most version control aware environments have git integration.

Shared repository does not necessarily mean Github. Nor does a GUI client, there's several to choose from. I suggest to research which one your prefer, and create a local repo right away.

With an editor and a version control tool, you can think about how you will deploy. Command line git can clone from the repo right into your server.  Or come up with your own way of packaging and installing your releases.

Comment: Ok so github is where I will likely create my project and I can push/pull/clone using git commands from the cmd or in VisualStudio the console PM. I was just curious because Im going to be developing in one server environment and deploying in another but using the same CMS. I think that will be my biggest challenge in regards to packaging up and releasing my project. That is my goal at least. I know its nice to be able to share your work too especially when looking for new employment.

Comment: Thanks btw. I was looking for a simple straight-forward answer that would send me in the right direction. I installed GIT a long time ago and I know there is an add-on for visual studio too but I had difficulties with it pushing the commit to github. The hard part is going to be getting comfortable with these tools and how to use them in regards to the specific project.